# Django Models Permission For Fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

let's say I've manually created three groups and three users through the admin site. Additionally, I have the following model:

```
class Export(models.Model):
    export_group1  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    export_group2  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    export_group3  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How can I ensure that 'user1,' with the assigned permissions of 'group1,' only has access to the field 'export_group1'? Is it possible to implement this in the models.py file?